# Custom Port Number in SvelteKit Node Production App

Tags: node.js, sveltekit, pm2, dotenv, sveltekit-adapter-node

According to [the docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables-port-host-and-socket-path), in order to use a custom port number for my SvelteKit app running with a Node adapter, I'm supposed to install `dotenv` and then add this to my `.env` file:

```bash
HOST=127.0.0.1 PORT=3003 node build
```

I then build my app with:

```bash
node -r dotenv/config build
```

...and I see this error:

```bash
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 127.0.0.1 PORT=3003 node build
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:2066:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:17) {
  errno: -3008,
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: '127.0.0.1 PORT=3003 node build'
```

If I ignore that and do a regular `npm build` and push my build up to my Node server, and try starting it with `pm2`:

```bash
pm2 start index.js
```

...it throws an error because port `3000` (the SvelteKit default) is in use by one of my other apps.

But if I bypass all these shenanigans, and modify `index.js` on the production server to change the port manually, the app works!

```js
const path = env('SOCKET_PATH', false);
const host = env('HOST', '0.0.0.0');
const port = env('PORT', !path && '3003'); //<-- Manually edit here like a caveman 

const server = polka().use(handler);

server.listen({ path, host, port }, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${path ? path : host + ':' + port}`);
});

export { host, path, port, server };
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the app to bake-in the custom port number when I first build the app?

Answer (score 0):

Since the error mentions this line:

```
hostname: '127.0.0.1 PORT=3003 node build'
```

it means the node think the hostname is this whole string `'127.0.0.1 PORT=3003 node build'`

and unless i'm mistaken the `.env` file should look more like this:

```
HOST=127.0.0.1
PORT=3003
```

so each variable on it's own line. And it should only include variables so no `node` or `build`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I separate the values in `.env` like you suggested, I can run `node -r dotenv/config build` without an error. However, `npm run build` still produces port `3000` in my `index.js` file. So something still isn't quite right. Perhaps the documentation is wrong.

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Well since there is more then one way how to run build it depends on your setup. If the command in package.js for build has "vite" in it then check the vite docs. Just googling "vite.config port" will give you the answer.